# I cant post to localhost with axios help please?

Tags: express, axios

I am trying to send data to localhost with axios post, But for some reason what ever I try, I get the same error

"not send Error: Network Error"

this is my front end code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {  }
}

sendData =()=>{
var url ="http://localhost:9000/api"
var data={
  code:"hello world",
}
axios.post(url,data)
.then(res => {
  console.log("data send")

})
.catch(err => {
  console.log("not send"+err)
  console.error(err); 
})

}
render() { 
return ( 
  <div>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="data"/>
    </form>
    {this.sendData()}
  </div>
 );
}
}

export default App;
```

and this is my back end code

```
var express=require('express');

var app=express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api', function(req,res){
res.json(req.body);
})

app.listen(9000);
```

Comment: are u sure your internet is working fine? plus replace the localhost with 127.0.0.1 and check your api is working perfectly on postman or not.

Comment: // POST
const userData = {
 var url ="http://localhost:9000/api"
var data={
  code:"hello world"
}

 , replace above code with senddata code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the error as well. It is most likely to be A CORS issue. If you can call the API from A Rest Client like Postman and not browser it is a CORS Issue

Install cors package `npm install cors`
Update your backed to allow CORS

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors') // New
var app = express()

app.use(cors()) // New
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api', function(req,res){
res.json(req.body);
})

app.listen(9000);
```